# How to perform large dataframe lookup in databricks with PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, databricks

We have a dataframe that has been loaded from a large national postal address database. This address dataframe contains approximately 30 million rows, each row being an address of either a geographical site, building, household, ext… There are around 5 to 8 potential columns that can be used to uniquely identify a specific address. These are columns like BuildingNumber, BuildingName, StreetName, TownName, CityName, PostCode, ext… In addition, there are also several alternative columns for each of those like SiteName, FieldName, SubBuildingName for BuildingName; Thoroughfare, StreetDescription for StreetName; PostTown, Locality, AdministrativeArea for TownName, PostCodeIn, PostCodeOut for PostCode, ext…

We ingest a daily dataset consisting of between 300 and 800 site/building data into a dataframe that we then need to attempt to match against that previous national address dataframe. This daily dataframe largely semi-structured and has the basic address columns like BuildingNumber, BuildingName, Street, Town, PostCode, ext…

I have to build a PySpark data pipeline to attempt to get as close as possible matches, which can then be subjected to further analysis by manual intervention or another sub-process.

For the moment I have been trying to do this using a complex join operation which looks like the one below:

```
sitedata_df.alias(“s”).join(nationaladdress_df.alias(“n”),
    ( (
        (col(“s.BuildingNumber”) == col(“n.BuildingNumber”)) |
        (col(“s.BuildingNumber”).isNull())
    ) &
    (
        (col(“s.BuildingName”) == col(“n.BuildingName”)) |
        (col(“s.BuildingName”) == col(“n.SiteName”)) |
        (col(“s.BuildingName”) == col(“n.FieldName”)) |
        (col(“s.BuildingName”) == col(“n.SubBuildingName”)) |
        (col(“s.BuildingName”).isNull())
    ) &
    (
        (col(“s.Street”) == col(“n.StreetName”)) |
        (col(“s.Street”) == col(“n.Thoroughfare”)) |
        (col(“s.Street”) == col(“n.StreetDescription”)) |
        (col(“s.Street”).isNull())
    ) &
    (
        (col(“s.Town”) == col(“n.TownName”)) |
        (col(“s.Town”) == col(“n.PostTown”)) |
        (col(“s.Town”) == col(“n.Locality”)) |
        (col(“s.Town”) == col(“n.AdministrativeArea”)) |
        (col(“s.Town”).isNull())
    ) &
    (
        (col(“s.PostCode”) == col(“n.PostCode”)) |
        (col(“s.PostCode”) == col(“n.PostCodeIn”)) |
        (col(“s.PostCode”) == col(“n.PostCodeOut”)) |
        (col(“s.PostCode”).isNull())
    )), “inner” )
```

Please note that for the sake of brevity I have left out a large number of additional alternative OR conditions from the above query which I will need to include in the actual query. I have tested this query with a limited dataset of around 50 rows in the sitedata_df dataframe and although the query does produce a reasonable result set, I feel it does not and will not perform well with a volume of 800 rows.

My questions are:

- Is there a better way to perform a lookup against a large dataframe instead using a join operation ?
- Is there a better way to combine the logical conditions instead of using OR ?
- I have read in some blog post a suggestion to use something like Elastic Search with Databricks for these types of lookups. Is that or a similar technology a more viable solution ?

I appreciate that this is a long question, but I wanted to make sure that my query is fully understood. Please let me know if anything is not clear and I will provide what ever information is required.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Broadcast Small DataFrame:**
If the smaller DataFrame can fit in the memory of each worker node, you can broadcast it to all nodes to avoid unnecessary shuffling. Use the broadcast function from the pyspark.sql.functions module.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
large_df = large_df.join(broadcast(small_df), "common_column")
```

**Persist or Cache DataFrames:**
If you're going to perform multiple operations on the resulting DataFrame, consider persisting or caching the DataFrames in memory or on disk. This can improve the performance of subsequent operations.

```
large_df.persist()
small_df.persist()

result_df = large_df.join(small_df, on="common_column", how="inner")

large_df.unpersist()
small_df.unpersist()
```